# Stack Overflow Credits: How and Where: 2022

Tags: android, kotlin

Running into more problems than coding itself!

Found something about an MIT credit, https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT but I just want to know how to credit SO, (stackoverflow.com) the beautiful thing it is.

Lots of stuff pre and post 2016, most of which I don't understand. And now Google is asking me to add a privacy statement and all I did was copy a statement to the web.

How do I credit Stack Overflow? If I put credits in my source, it's compiled in ones and o's. So as far as I know, unless reverse compiled, humans can't read it.

I've been writing in several languages over many years in our great government and private freeware, and my method has been to write an About dialog box with credits. But, with the Play Store, the author/date/everything is already posted with the app. So, should I post the credits there?

Note: When I post code I want programmers to use it: even runnable!

And too: even look at my 'screen name' as I chose not to use my name, but a word play on IntelliSense!

Finally: where do I get the SO icon to display for credits?

Example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.app.name.MainActivity">
<!--    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />-->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_credits"
        android:title="@string/add_credits"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If you're adding licences, attributions etc to an app, you're just supposed to put them somewhere people can see them - a section in the settings is typical. There are libraries that will handle it for you

Comment: @cactustictacs Thanks, really! That is a cool 'screen name' if I can figure that out what that is. Now: exactly: I want Stack Overflow to let me attribute the right way.  And since International as we know the beautiful web is, to add the SO icon in an overflow menu item. And I can't say thanks enough for your reply. It certainly looks reasonable.

Comment: Also: getting an icon in the menu item(s) would be good.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow's content is licenced under *CC BY-SA* - there's [a link at the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) that gives more details. There's [a longer blog post here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) that explains it a bit more, it's from 2009 but it should all still apply (the same licence is in use and that's the important thing - just newer revisions for newer content).

Branding stuff including logos and icons is [here](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/logo/).

I'm not giving any advice on what you need to attribute and what you don't - using some code from an answer in your app isn't the same thing as reproducing that code (or answers in general) in human-readable form, but you need to make that call for yourself, depending on what you're doing.

I'm not sure you need to post attributions on your Play Store listing (unless they're specifically about the listing itself, e.g. art assets you've used in your store branding). Again, not advice, read the licences you need to comply with, but in my experience they generally say that they have to be made available for the user to read, and it's a typical recommendation to have a section for it within the app itself.

Some licences also require attribution where the licenced content is visible (e.g. directly under it, informing the user of where it came from) but the actual licence text (which you usually need to provide, or a link to it) can be elsewhere. Again, check the licence!

Comment: Thank goodness for this response! Stepping on toes is not the way to get ahead. And we all know there's a big market waiting out there too!